# How to change the thumbs up icon in Facebook Messenger chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

In Facebook Messenger in the web browser or the messenger app, there is a thumbs up sticker button out by default. People I know changed it to some other icons by default, but I can't ask them how.

I don't see any option for it, yet somehow it was changed. After you change it, it will say

> <person name> set the emoji to <emoji here>.

Can anyone tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine doesn't show the option of the I either - you have to go into a chat and click the persons name at the top - there it will give you the option to change color text and emoji :)

Answer (score 4):

Using Facebook Messenger, at the conversation window, go to:

**Details (top-right) --> Emoji --> Pick your Emoji.**

There's no option to change Emoji using the web version yet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see that option on the app

Comment: @omega Facebook Messenger, not Facebook app. Check again, it should be there.

Comment: Yep I did, those options are not there for me

Comment: is it android or ios specific? I am on android

Comment: @omega I'm on android too. My Facebook Messenger version is 53.0.0.17.308 if that helps.

Comment: I'm on 52.0.0.19.66 on note4. When I check for updates on play store, messenger app is not there.

Comment: i finally got the update to do this now